# How to not repeat validation in java

Tags: javascript, java, validation, methods

I'm writing a program that calculates the price of painting rooms in a house.
The program asks the user a couple of questions and the user must input certain answers regarding the topic. The program must also implement validation's where 0 and negative numbers are not accepted:

```
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Number of rooms to be painted?");
  noRooms = keyboard.nextDouble();  

  while (noRooms <= 0) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input for the number of rooms. Please enter in the appropriate number:");
    noRooms = keyboard.nextDouble();    

  System.out.println("Number of sqaure feet of wall space in each room?");
  wallSpace = keyboard.nextDouble();

  while (wallSpace <= 0) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input for the number of square feet of wall space. Please enter in the appropriate number:");
    wallSpace = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

My validation is correct however I have been informed that I must NOT repeat the validations for each input and create only one validation, place it in a method and apply it to each input.

```
public static void validation(Scanner keyboard, double noRooms, double wallSpace) {    
 while (noRooms <= 0 || wallSpace <= 0) {
   System.out.println("Invalid Input: Please enter in the appropriate number:");
   noRooms , wallSpace = keyboard.nextDouble();
     }
}
```

I understand the code above is incorrect and what I must do is implement the method, that combines all the input values, and apply it to the one validation. Any suggestions?

--UPDATE--

So I got the idea of creating the validation like so:

```
private static double validation(Scanner keyboard) {
double v = keyboard.nextDouble();
  while (v <= 0) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input: Please enter in the appropriate number:");
}
return v;
}
```

And to call it within the input like:

```
System.out.println("Number of rooms to be painted:");
noRoom= keyboard.nextDouble();
noRoom= validation(keyboard);
```

No errors appear but the program doesn't do anything when I input either the 'correct' or 'incorrect' data. Is there another way to call the method?

Comment: Have a method which takes a scanner, a prompt, an error message, and an error boundary and returns the requested input.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you extract a method to prompt for the value and call it twice. Something like,

```
static double getValidValue(Scanner sc, String initial, String msg) {
    System.out.println(initial);
    double v = sc.nextDouble();
    while (v <= 0) {
        System.out.printf("Invalid input for the %s. "
                + "Please enter in the appropriate number:%n", msg);
    }
    return v;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    double noRooms = getValidValue(keyboard,
            "Number of rooms to be painted?", "number of rooms");
    double wallSpace = getValidValue(keyboard,
            "Number of sqaure feet of wall space in each room?",
            "number of square feet of wall space");
    // ... noRooms and wallSpace are > 0.
}
```

Comment: I did something similar but no output appears when I run the program and input the data.

Comment: @user3622970 No, what you did is not really similar. Note that you forgot to print a message before prompting for input.